# CoffeeScript how to make iteration return an associative array?

Tags: arrays, loops, coffeescript

So I have a jQuery object (an array of DOM objects) like this `$('#items-filters input, #items-filters select')`. Now I want to collect data from these elements with HTML attribute name as keys. First thing to do is

```
data = ($(element).val() for element in $('#items-filters input, #items-filters select'))
```

But this returns a regular array with the values `["x", "y"]`, so I tried this:

```
values = for element in $('#items-filters input, #items-filters select')
    k = $(element).attr('name')
    "#{k}": $(element).val()
```

Which returns an array of associative arrays like this `[{"name1": "x"}, {"name2": "y"}]`

At this point I just did it the 'traditional' js way with a side-effect loop rather than a value-returning loop, but I really like the concept of value-returning loops. So is there any way to solve this in the 'CoffeeScript way'?

My (I hope) temporary working code:

```
values = {}
for element in $('#items-filters input, #items-filters select')
    k = $(element).attr('name')
    values[k] = $(element).val()
```

(values = `{"name1": "x", "name2": "y"}`)

Comment: That's as good as it gets unless you want to use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) but that's cumbersome.

Comment: List comprehensions return...wait for it... **lists**. Unfortunately you can't make them return a hash instead. If you still wish containment use `reduce` or wrap your loop in an IIFE.